# what is id() of a python class, not class instance

Tags: python, class, object, identity

From the python document the id() function:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.

This is clear, I understand it. It a python class instance is passed to id function, it returns the “identity” / address of that object.  However, if a python class name is passed to id function. What does it return?  From example.

```
class Abc:
    value = 0

x = Abc()

id(x)  # -> 65097560

id(Abc)  # -> 67738424
```

I understand 65097560 is the memory address of object `x`. but what is the meaning of `id(Abc)` / `67738424`?

Comment: Classes are objects. All the same information applies.

Comment: It returns the identity of the object `ABC`. Since everything is an object you can even get the identity of functions e.g. `print(id(abs))`.

Comment: `Abc` is just an instance of `type`, which you can observe by evaluating `type(Abc)`.

Comment: @Matthias Or `id(id)` :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy That was a good one.

Comment: Any deeper "meaning" of the ID is implementation-dependent.  For most implementations, this will be the memory address of the `type` instance object, just as it is with other objects.

Comment: Related: [What is meant by classes themselves are objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6482207/4518341), [Relationship between objects and classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5050654/4518341)

Comment: You're not passing the class name, you're passing the class.

Answer (score 1):

[Classes are objects themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6482207/4518341). They're instances of the [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/4518341) [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). (`type` is also used for determining something's type.)

```py
>>> class Abc: pass
... 
>>> type(Abc)
<class 'type'>
>>> id(Abc)
39363368
```

In Python 2, old-style classes are instances of `classobj`.

```
>>> class Old: pass
... 
>>> type(Old)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> id(Old)
140369496387664
>>> class New(object): pass
... 
>>> type(New)
<type 'type'>
>>> id(New)
94676790299104
```

In general, [everything is an object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/865911/4518341), including functions like `id()` itself, builtin types/classes like `list`, and modules like `sys`. Though there are a few exceptions like keywords and operators.